# Reverse for 'day_new' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['date/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/new/$']

Tags: python, django

this is my first django project and it seems like I don't understand something about primary keys

I have 2 models and want to add them to 1 form
but I'm getting this error

> Reverse for 'day_new' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1
> pattern(s) tried: ['date/(?P[0-9]+)/new/$']

my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import reverse
from django.conf import settings
class MyDate(models.Model):
    english_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False)
    hebrew_date = models.CharField(max_length=20,unique=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("date_detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.hebrew_date

class MyDateDetails(models.Model):
    date = models.ForeignKey('luach.MyDate',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sof_zman_1 = models.TimeField(auto_now=False,blank=True,null=True)
    sof_zman_2 = models.TimeField(auto_now=False,blank=True,null=True)
    sof_zman_tefila = models.TimeField(auto_now=False,blank=True,null=True)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)
    ad_image = models.ImageField(unique=False,blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date)

class Image(models.Model):
    date = models.ForeignKey('luach.MyDate',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(unique=False,upload_to='images')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("date_detail",kwargs={'pk':MyDate.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date)
```

my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404,redirect
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from luach.models import (MyDate,Image,MyDateDetails,MazelTov)
    
def create_day_view(request,pk):
    date = get_object_or_404(MyDate,pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        length = request.POST.get('length')
        sof_zman_1 = request.POST.get('sof_zman_1')
        sof_zman_2 = request.POST.get('sof_zman_2')
        sof_zman_tefila = request.POST.get('sof_zman_tefila')
        ad_image = request.POST.get('ad_image')

        day_details = MyDateDetails.objects.create(
            sof_zman_1 = sof_zman_1,
            sof_zman_2 = sof_zman_2,
            sof_zman_tefila = sof_zman_tefila,
            ad_image = ad_image,
        )
        
        for file_num in range(0, int(length)):
            Image.objects.create(
                date = date,
                image = request.FILES.get(f'images{file_num}')
            )

    context = {'date': date}
    return render(request, 'luach/create_day.html')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('date/<int:pk>/new/',views.create_day_view,name='day_new')
]
```

create_day.html

```
{% extends 'luach/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<label>sof zman 1</label>
<input type="time" id="sof_zman_1" class="form-control">
<label>sof zman 2</label>
<input type="time" id="sof_zman_2" class="form-control">
<label>sof zman tefila</label>
<input type="time" id="sof_zman_tefila" class="form-control">
<label>ad image</label>
<input type="file" id="ad_image" class="form-control">
<label>Images</label>
<input type="file" multiple>

<button type="button" id="saveBtn" class="btn btn-primary mt-4">Save</button>

<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var files = []
        FilePond.registerPlugin(FilePondPluginFileValidateSize);
        FilePond.registerPlugin(FilePondPluginFileValidateType);
        FilePond.setOptions({
            allowMultiple:true,
            maxFiles:10,
            maxFileSize: '10MB'
        })
        const inputElement = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
        const pond = FilePond.create( inputElement, {
            acceptedFileTypes:['image/png', 'image/jpeg'],
            onaddfile: (err, fileItem) => {
                if (!err) {
                files.push(fileItem.file)
                }
                console.log(files)
            },
            onremovefile: (err, fileItem) => {
                const index = files.indexOf(fileItem.file)
                if (index > -1) {
                    files.splice(index, 1)
                }
                console.log(files)
            }
        } );

        var formData = new FormData();
        $(document).on('click', '#saveBtn', function(e) {
            formData.append('length', files.length)
            formData.append('sof_zman_1', $('#sof_zman_1').val())
            formData.append('sof_zman_2', $('#sof_zman_2').val())
            formData.append('sof_zman_tefila', $('#sof_zman_tefila').val())
            formData.append('ad_image', $('#ad_image').val())
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                formData.append('images' + i, files[i])
            }
            formData.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', '{{ csrf_token }}')

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '{% url "day_new" pk=mydate.pk %}',
                data: formData,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                success: function (){
                    window.location.href = "{% url 'date_detail' pk=mydate.pk %}";
                },
                error: function(xhr, errmsg, err) {
                    console.log(xhr.status + ":" + xhr.responseText)
                }
            })
        })
    })
</script>
{% endblock  %}
```

Comment: In your template `mydate` does not exists.

Comment: Or mydate.pk return None, try to use mydate.id

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the context but not passing it through render. Your view should be updated to.

```
 context = {'date': date}
 return render(request, 'luach/create_day.html', context=context)
```

and in your template.. you should use "date" instead of "mydate"